# how to use mysql stored procedure in java with dynamic arugments?

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

[image]
there are three fixed arguments in this little Java project, and the first two arguments are all fixed arguments. And I want to know, if there is a way to use stored procedure with the arguments that is not fixed in the project. For example I want to execute the procedure with arguement v1, and I think I might use 
"CallableStatement cstmt =  conn.prepareCall("{call proc_2(v1,'b',?)}");
But obviously it's wrong. 
So my problem is how the sql sentence can get the varibale from java?

Comment: if the first two argument is fixed why do you still pass in into the prepared call? shouldn't it already be coded in the sql statement itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use question marks as placeholders for dynamic arguments too.
For example:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call proc_2('a', ?, ?)}");
cstmt.setString(1, aString);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
boolean i = cstmt.execute();
```